# How to pass parameter from a controller by db query in Yii

Tags: php, arrays, yii-extensions, yii

Here is my controller::

```
public function actionCreateGRN($id){
            $model = new VwPurchaseordhd;
            $sql = sprintf("call sp_im_CreateGRN(%s,'%s')",
                   $id,
                   $insertuser = Yii::app()->user->name
                );
           $command  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
           $result = $command->queryAll();

         $this->redirect(array('grndetail/create', 'id'=>$model->id, 'pp_purordnum'=>$pp_purordnum, ));
    }
```

In $result I have an array:: Array ( [0] => Array ( [pp_purordnum] => PO1400000291 [vGrnNumber] => GR14007320 ) )

I need to pass array data via "redirect" to another controller/function. It's showing ERROR undefined pp_purordnum. I am missing something.

Could you please help me to pass parameter what I have in array ? Thanks in Advance.

## SOLVED

## Controller

```
        public function actionCreateGRN($id){
            $sql = sprintf("call sp_im_CreateGRN(%s,'%s')",
                   $id,
                   $insertuser = Yii::app()->user->name
                );
           $command  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
           $result = $command->queryRow();

           $pp_purordnum = $result['pp_purordnum'];
           $vGrnNumber = $result['vGrnNumber'];

         $this->redirect(array('grndetail/create', 'pp_purordnum'=>$pp_purordnum, 'vGrnNumber'=>$vGrnNumber, ));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $sql = "call sp_im_CreateGRN(:id, :user_name)"
   $command  = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
   $result = $command->queryAll(true, array(
       ':id'=>$id, 
       ':user_name'=>Yii::app()->user->name,
   ));
```

Comment: I found the solutions. and updated the code below the question.. thanks for your answer. I will need your code. It's really great ... please vote this question